# Convert linq query to lambda expression

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, lambda

I am having trouble converting this linq query to a lambda expression, I tried to solve it using `include` but not successful, please help

```
(from PS in _dbNavigation.Table1
 join CP in _dbNavigation.Table2 on PS.PropName equals CP.PropName
 where PS.IsDeleted == false && PS.UserName.Equals("REX")
 select CP).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
_dbNavigation.Table1
             .Join(_dbNavigation.Table2, t1 => t1.PropName, t2 => t2.PropName, (t1, t2) => new { t1, t2 })
             .Where(x => x.t1.IsDeleted == false && x.t2.UserName == "REX")
             .Select(x => x.t2);
```